# Add a number in the second element of each sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have:

```
a = [ [1,2], [2,9], [3,7] ]
```

I edited the second value of each list

```
seconds = [a[1] for num in a]
i = 0

while i <= len(seconds):
    seconds[i] += 3
```

How do I update the values to get this

```
a = [ [1,5], [2,12], [3,10] ]
```

Comment: Where is the "string"?

Comment: Your title does not match your question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of first saving `seconds` and then modifying, you could do it all in one:

```
a = [ [1,2], [2,9], [3,7] ]

for item in a:
    item[1] += 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `list comprehension`, with [`extended iterable unpacking`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) in order to only update the second element:

```
l = [ [1,2], [2,9], [3,7] ]
[[a, b + 3, *c] for a,b,*c in l]
[[1, 5], [2, 12], [3, 10]]
```

Which updates the second element of every sublist regardless of its length:

```
l = [ [1,2,5,10], [2,9,7,2], [3,7,1,5] ]
[[a, b + 3, *c] for a,b,*c in l]
[[1, 5, 5, 10], [2, 12, 7, 2], [3, 10, 1, 5]]
```

---

*Note*: This assumes that each sublist contains at least 2 elements

Comment: The OP didn't mention anywhere that the sublists would always be of size 2.

Comment: and you should also mention that this solution would only work if there are _at least_ two elements in every sublist.

Comment: Why would you want to extract only the second element otherwise? Besides that would only work catching an exception if it doesn't exist, but dont think OP needs this, plus the other solutions don't add this either...

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying that your answer is wrong, I actually gave it a +1, but I was just saying that its good to mention that, because there's no fallback in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple list comprehension would suffice:

```
a_2= [[each[0],each[1]+3] for each in a]
```

Printing a_2 would result in:

```
[[1, 5], [2, 12], [3, 10]]
```

Comment: Not valid Python code. `NameError: name 'each' is not defined`.

Comment: You will not get a NameError if you did what i just showed. I tried before posting my solution here.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Both [[each[0],each[1]+3] for each[0],each[1] in a] and [[each[0],each[1]+3] for each in a] work. Realize that I gain nothing by making something up!

Comment: `a_2= [[each[0],each[1]+3] for each[0],each[1] in a]` **doesn't** work. Try running again in a fresh terminal/editor from scratch

Comment: I'm sure that you haven't made anything up, but you must have accidentally defined `each` before this line.

Comment: tbh, I just defined 'a' in the previous line

Comment: Like both of you suggested, I tried in a fresh instance and it didn't work. My bad; I apologize.